# C# instance of object

Tags: c#

If a object is an instance of a class and instance is same as object as i see on the net  what is then instance of an object? Am really confused with this term instance i read a lot of definitions of instance and real world examples and i can't understand it confusing me a lot.

And to be sure i understood the term reference of an object..Reference is a pointer on object managed by CLR.
Pointers are chunk of memory that points on another chunk of memory. And reference types are types of data accessed through a pointer(reference) ?

Comment: The term `instance of an object` simply doesn't make sense.  Where did you see it?  Chances are it's a mistake.  Perhaps someone said "instance of `object`", as `object` is the name of a particular class in `C#` and several other languages.

Comment: As far as reference types go, your understanding, though somewhat oversimplified, is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class describes something - akin to a template - whilst an object is an instance of it.

For example, I might have a class called "car". It describes how a car starts, and that it has four doors, but you can't start its engine: it's just a description.

Using this class, the factory builds my car (they create my object for me). With this car, I can then start its engine and drive it away.

In terms of code, I would define `car` as:

```
  public class Car {

      public int Doors { get { return 4; } }

      public void StartEngine() {
          // start engine
      }

  }
```

The factory then makes it for me:

```
  Car MyCar = new Car();
```

I then drive it away:

```
  MyCar.StartEngine();
  MyCar.DriveAway();
```

Answer (score 5):

`object` is a C# synonym for the `System.Object` class. An instance of an `object` is an instance of the `System.Object` class. All classes extend `System.Object`, any instance of a class is an instance of `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a class `Foo`. When you want to create a `Foo` object you *instantiate* it like so:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
```

Now the object stored in the variable `myFoo` is an *instance* of the class Foo.

It just so happens that you can also say `Foo` is an *instance* of object, meaning `System.Object` because all classes in C# derive from it, but it's not a particularly helpful thing to say.

Answer (score 0):

Object is a contiguous block of memory that stores the actual information that distinguishes this object from other objects, while an instance is a reference to an object. It is a block of memory, which points to the staring address of where the object is stored. Two instances may refer to the same object. Life spans of an object and an instance are not related. Therefore an instance could be null. Once all instances pointing to an object is removed, the object will be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, I agree that 'Instance of **an** object' sounds tautological. *Instance of 'object'* would be better. However, it makes more sense if you think of 'object' as meaning 'the object class' as explained by dasblinkenlight.